# Do Stellarterm and Stellarport recognise some or none of the federated addresses?

Tags: wallets, federation, exchanges

Noticed that StellarPort and StellarTerm don't recognise a federated address for sending assets to, while it worked fine from Firefly wallet.

Does any dev or anybody else from either platform know why and could this possible be corrected so it will be easier to send?

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Most likely your CORS headers aren't setup, or setup incorrectly.

Websites are served on specific domains, and CORS header from an internet resource lets the browser know what domains are allowed to serve it.

Standalone apps don't care.

Comment: Thanks Johan, CORS headers have been enabled and tested, but still both Stellarport and Stellerterm don't seem to recognise the federated address. Below the result from the test: 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 11 Sep 2018 09:50:26 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Sat, 18 Aug 2018 10:42:42 GMT
ETag: "af4-573b35600a939"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 2804
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Do you have any other suggestions, maybe?

Thanks in advance